# add page numbers between last and next buttons, pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

Im using javascript pagination where im trying to get it to display 10 page numbers between the "previous" and "next" button and remove the "previous" button when it is on page #1. here is my code so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/405/

```
<div class="content">1 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">2 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">3 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">4 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">5 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">6 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">7 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">8 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">9 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">10 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">11 I have some content</div>
<div class="content">12 I have some content</div>

<ol id="pagin">
        <li><a id='previous' class="current" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a id='next' href="#">Next</a></li>
</ol>

pageSize = 3;
var i = 1;
showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
    });        
}

showPage(i);

$("#previous").click(function() {
    $("#next").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    if (i != 1) {
      showPage(--i);
    }
});
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#previous").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    if (i < ($('.content').length)/3) {
      showPage(++i);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all pages in between the prev and next button, you just have to know the number of pages which is, in that case,

```
var pages = Math.ceil($('.content').length / pageSize) // (12 = 4pages, 13 = 5pages)
```

You can do it in javascript. You add a container (let's just call it "id='pager'") and append the content in it such as:

```
for (var i = 0; i<pages; i++) {
   // We do not want page 0. You could have started with i = 1 too.
   $('#pager').append('<a href="#" class="pageClick">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
}
$('.pageClick').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // Index + 1 = the wanted page (index 0 = page 1)
   showPage($(this).index()+1);
});
```

Hope that helped
Of course, I haven't done it all, just the big lines

Answer (score 0):

Just add "jPages.js" file from

https://github.com/luis-almeida/jPages/tree/master/js

and add following code:

HTML code:
`<div class="holder" />`

```
 $(function(){
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID  : "itemContainer",
        perPage      : 10,
        startPage    : 1,
        startRange   : 1,
        midRange     : 5,
        endRange     : 1
    });
});
```